# lpsolve feedback during solve

Tags: rstudio, lpsolve

I am using lpsolver inside RStudio to solve a supply chain network optimization problem. The MILP model I am trying to solve is taking a lot of time. I want to know if it is possible to get some feedback from the model when it is solving. Feedback like current objective, current upper bound, etc should be sufficient for me.